# Why variable shadowing does not work in solidity remix?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;
    
    contract  variableshadowing {
        address owner;
        function self_delete() public returns(address) {
            require(owner == msg.sender);
            selfdestruct(owner);
        }
    
    }
    
    contract child is variableshadowing {
        address owner;
        function shadow(){
            owner = msg.sender;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

After solidity 0.6 shadowing state variable is not allowed anymore!

"State variable shadowing is now disallowed. A derived contract can only declare a state variable x, if there is no visible state variable with the same name in any of its bases."

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/060-breaking-changes.html

https://solidity-by-example.org/shadowing-inherited-state-variables/